# Are there any stories of Eisheth in Jewish Kabbalah feeding on souls

Tags: abrahamic-religions, demons, judaism, middle-east

"Kabbalistic writings mention Eisheth is responsible for the creation of the Shedim (type of demon). Eisheth feeds upon the souls of humans, specifically those that have fallen from the virtuous ways of God. Upon devouring them, she would regurgitate these souls back out, distorting and warping them into hideous demons that mirror the sins and darkness these souls once committed on Earth."

Is this an actual story or belief in certain Jewish thought?

Comment: Can you share the reference from where you found this and any other supplemental information you might have?

Comment: @cmw https://the-demonic-paradise.fandom.com/wiki/Eisheth_Zenunim under the Kabbalah sub-heading